# How can I use regular expression to match urls starting with https and ending with #?

Tags: regex

Very much a newb with regex and having a hard time figuring this one out. I have an HTML document and I want to clear out a ton of URLs that are inside of it. All of the URLs begin with https:// and they all end with a pound sign #.

Any help would be extremely appreciative. Using sublime text for my editor in case that is needed.

Comment: Start by reading some regex tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic way to do it:

```
\bhttps://[^\s#]+#
```

free-spaced:

```
\b                 //word start
https://           
[^\s#]+            //followed by anything but whitespace and '#'
#
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to clear everything in between the url from `https:// [...] #` then you can use:

```
^(https)+(.)*(#)+$
```

But you may want to be more specific in terms of what you are filtering out.  If this is from a database query you should be ok since you can assume the URL will be the content of the field(s) returned the you will be running the regex through a code loop of some kind.

BTW you can hone your scripts using something like http://regexpal.com/

Comment: `(.)*` needs to be changed to `(.*)`, or you'll just capture the last *character*, and `(https)+` can be changed to `https`. You don't need to capture it, and it's definitely not going to repeat.